# How to call a method with multiple parameters in BlueZ?

Tags: c, glib, dbus, bluez

```
            GVariantBuilder *b;
            GVariant *obex_dict;
            b = g_variant_builder_new(G_VARIANT_TYPE ("a{sv}"));
            g_variant_builder_add(b, "{sv}", "Target", g_variant_new_string("ftp"));
            obex_dict = g_variant_builder_end(b);
            
            g_dbus_connection_call_sync(
                    conn,
                    BLUEZ_ORG,
                    "/org/bluez/obex",
                    "org.bluez.obex.Client1",
                    "CreateSession",
                    g_variant_new("(s{sv})", g_variant_new_string("/org/bluez/hci0/dev_5C_87_30_66_F4_35"), obex_dict),
                    NULL,
                    G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE,
                    -1,
                    NULL,
                    &error);

            if (error != NULL)
                g_error(error->message);
```

I'm getting these errors when I run this:

```
(process:52242): GLib-CRITICAL **: 10:48:51.980: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'g_utf8_validate (string, -1, NULL)' failed 
(process:52242): GLib-CRITICAL **: 10:48:51.980: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'g_utf8_validate (string, -1, NULL)' failed
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've checked the type strings.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the signature of the method parameters should be `(sa{sv})`. `{xy}` is one dictionary entry of type `x` to type `y`, and a dictionary is conceptually an "array" of dictionary entries.